# conversion between list of objects and Gson string

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I'm converting a list of objects to json string and then back to list of objects as below:

```
List<Work> list = new ArrayList<Work>();
Work w1 = new Work();
Work w2 = new Work();
list.add(w1);
list.add(w2);

String str = GsonUtils.getJsonString(list);

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Work>>() {
}.getType();
List<Work> list1 = new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
```

this works completely fine and returns the list `List<Work>`.

Now I'm doing same by extracting a method as below:

```
List<Work> list = new ArrayList<Work>();
Work w1 = new Work();
Work w2 = new Work();
list.add(w1);
list.add(w2);

String str = GsonUtils.getJsonString(list);

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Work>>() {
}.getType();
List<Work> list1 = getListFromJSON(str, Work.class);
```

where method is defined as below:

```
public <T> List<T> getListFromJSON(String str, Class<T> type) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<T> list = new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
    return list;
}
```

this time it's resulting into an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to com.restfb.types.User$Work
    at expt.ExptGsonList.main(ExptGsonList.java:45)
```

Please help me to know where am I going wrong and how can I get this working using method?

Answer (score 0):

Change the method signature to

```
public <T> List<T> getListFromJSON(String str, Type type)
```

and pass listType

Comment: I changed as you said and then `List<T> list = new Gson().fromJson(str, type);`. this resulted into error: `Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2`

Comment: Change the return value also to List<Work> instead of List<T>

Comment: I can't do that.. I'm writing a method to make it applicable for any class objects.

Comment: I am basically pointing to Class<T> type which you passed as parameter but did not use. Also, shouldn't the return type be <List<T> instead of <T> List<T>

Comment: `<T> List<T>` is not the return type.. return type is `List<T>` and `<T>` is just type parameter for method.